# Poor performance with postgresql database in RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dplyr, rds

I am experiencing problems while trying to retrieve a small fraction of the database table that is stored in RDS amazon instance.

Using R, from an EC2 instance, I exported multiple data frames to an RDS database using dplyr package. This was done by running a loop, appending the data to a large table (200 GiB) stored in the RDS instance:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, value = df, name = "oco2v8", append = TRUE)
```

Then, I open a postgresql connection, creating a tbl followed by some filtering:

```
conn1 = dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), 
                 host="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com", 
                 port=5432,
                 user="XXXX",
                 password="XXXXX",
                 dbname="oco2v8")
oco2data <- tbl(conn1, my_table_name)
filtered <- filter(oco2data, latitude > 92 & latitude < 98 & longitude > 34 & longitude < 40 & xco2_quality_flag == 0)
```

The filtering takes much longer than expected, usually couple of minutes. The bigger problem starts when I use the collect() command to import the subset data to my R environment.

```
my_df <- filtered %>% collect()
```

After **long hours** the command eventually does the work, but I don't understand why it is extremely slow, as the subset data is around 600kb. 
The RDS instance specifications are as follows: 
  - **Type: db.t2.medium, Micro Instance - Current Generation

  - Memory: 4 GiB

  - CPU Number of virtual cores: 2 vCPU

  - EBS optimized: No

  - Network Performance: Moderate

  - Both the EC2 and the RDS instances are hosted in US east (Ohio) region.**

I have tried to increase the memory and network performance to the highest possible, changed the multi AZ parameter to yes, worked via psql command line and worked through my local machine - nothing solved the problem. Also, I tried to change the specifications of the EC2 instance from which I connect to the RDS instance.

What could be the reason for this poor performance?
Does someone have experience with using RDS instance via EC2?
Is there an alternative for the collect() command?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Dor

Comment: Do you get significantly better performance running on a local database? How does running the query in R compare to using SQL? How many rows are in the table? Do you have any indexes? Does the RDS monitoring show high CPU consumption (and more important, does it suddenly drop and stay low -- if yes, the use an "M" instance type rather than the "T")? Does the disk IO performance flatline at a certain level?

Comment: Hi @kdgregory, thanks for your reply. To your questions: 1. Performance is not better when I run things from a local machine, might be even slower.  2. The table in the database contains tens of thousands rows (not sure about the exact number). The subset datadrame to extract however is quite small (~500 rows and 90 variables). To the rest of the issues, I did not observe issues with CPU consumption or IO performance - it seems like changing the instance type and memory did not have a significant affect on the runtime (tryout with db.m4.10xlarge instance took 1.5 hours to collect() the data)

Comment: correction: The number of rows in the table is 185,969,072

Comment: Your answer to (1) is unclear: I was looking to compare a _database_ running locally, to rule out any innate performance issues in RDS. The second question that I asked (that you didn't answer) was to rule out any quirks of running in R, versus plain SQL (such as R reading all rows to apply the filter).

Comment: But, given the large number of rows, it seems like you simply need to add an index on the relevant columns. A composite index on latitude and longitude would be best.

Comment: If adding an index solves the problem, you should write that up as a self-answer. I tried to search for other questions that covered the same ground (to mark this one as a duplicate) but couldn't find any that were good matches. It seems there should be _something_, but maybe I wasn't using the right search terms.

Comment: I will try to work it out with indexes and update soon! thanx

Comment: The issue is solved by adding indices to the postgresql table and CLUSTER by them. Thanks a lot!